# "in this regard" vs. "in this respect"

Tags: phrase-meaning, adverbs

What is the usage of "in this regard", I didn't find good examples or definition to get its usage. When is it used? What is its difference with "in this respect" or any "in this X" that I don't know.

The following sentences are some examples showing how I think about them and use them:

> Some students may have auditory problem; **in this regard**, teachers should get sure a student hear the words correctly.
>
> The internet speed is low in this country; **in this respect**, it is one of the worst countries to use internet.
>
> In my opinion, the teacher treated the student badly; **in this regard**, I prefer to not speak more.
>
> There is a shortage of skilled labor in this city. Decision makers should do something **in this regard**.
>
> I can't understand the Einstein theories. **In this regard** my knowledge is incomplete.
>
> He runs very fast. **In this respect** he is one of the fastest boys I have ever seen.

Is my sense of them correct?

Comment: Just use Google ngram for this sort of question: `in this regard, in this respect` and then click on the results links to see actual uses. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+this+regard%2Cin+this+respect&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20this%20regard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20this%20respect%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano Ok! I added my sentences to the question, I also searched and looked the dictionary, but their definition or examples give me no idea. Google says it is used "in connection with the point previously mentioned."
"there was little incentive for them to be active in this regard". but when I don't know the previous sentence, I can't find it.

Comment: @TRomano by the way I should say, google ngram is banned for Iranians!!! the politics.

Comment: As I said, the tools for answering this sort of question are abundant. You will get a far better sense of how to use these phrases by examining these phrases in actual use than you will from some abstract definition. They're virtually interchangeable.  The main nuance will be their placement in the sentence.

Comment: I did not know that Google ngram was banned for Iranians. Is Google banned?

Comment: Are you able to see the results of this search? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20this%20regard%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @TRomano some features of Google or some other sites are banned, but not the google search or gmail. however the rest which are not banned are filtered by the Iran regime like facebook, youtube, (twitter is not), wordpress, blogger, BlogSpot, BBC... though I can open them though some software

Comment: @TRomano in fact, there are similar adverbs in Persian which are used much, if they are the same then I can get sure I got them right, I brought some examples of my understanding of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In this regard** and **in this respect** refer back to an *idea* expressed in the previous statement.

Consider your example:

> There is a shortage of skilled labor in this city. Decision makers
>   should do something in this regard.

The second sentence can be paraphrased:

**Decision makers should do something *about that*.**

where "that" refers to the shortage of skilled labor in that city.

Or this example:

> The internet speed is low in this country; in this respect, it is one
>   of the worst countries to use internet.

The second sentence could be paraphrased:

**... *in terms of speed*, it is one of the worst places to use the internet.**

or

***when the criterion is speed*, it is one of the worst places to use the internet.**

"in this respect" refers to the slowness that is mentioned in the preceding clause.

Comment: Thank you very much, then you say my usage of the phrase in my examples are sensible and correct?

Comment: I would say that there is really no need for an "in this regard" in that sentence, and that the core idea of your first clause is not clear enough to support an "in this regard".  Your first clause refers to the examination of "the features" in order to determine whether a node is a text node. One could say simply *To determine whether a node is a text node, its features are examined. All nodes are examined in the same way.*

Comment: thank you, but just why "All nodes"? should I say "all the nodes"?!, however I like "all nodes" better.

Comment: No, you should not say "all the nodes".

Comment: How about this? "*The features employed in the extraction rules are used to determine whether each node of the DOM tree is a text node or not. For this purpose, all nodes may be examined in the same way.*"

Comment: We're on different wavelengths, Ahmad. I find these sentences vague and needlessly wordy.

Comment: I see, just it is a bit vague by its nature, the features are not just the features of the nodes (as it is in your sentence), those are something that are specified by the rules. for example if the rule tells **skin color**, then each person is examined just by his skin color (not all his features), if the rule specifies skin color and eye color, each person is examined using these two features. (however I work on it and your sentence is helpful)

Comment: Are you saying that the extraction rules apply the same tests to all nodes, i.e. without regard for node location, to determine whether the node is a text node?

Comment: Yes, the extraction rules treat all nodes the same way, they test specified features to check if they are text node or not, regardless of their location. You can forget *features*, as you said the rules are the same for all nodes and do the same test. while multiple rules could be defined in replace of a rule which each covers a specific section.

Comment: Interestingly, when I want to explain the issue here, I use better sentences!

Answer (score 1):

"In this regard", "in this respect", "in this vein" all have the same meaning. They are used to give more details or illustrations about something.